# Getting child class name in super() constructor

Tags: java, oop

I have two Java classes `TeradataTable` and `RdbmsTable`-

Useful part of `RdbmsTable.java`

```
public class RdbmsTable {

    public RdbmsTable(String uri, String type) {
       this.uri = uri;
       this.type = type;
    }
```

Useful part of `TeradataTable.java`

```
public class TeradataTable extends RdbmsTable {

    public TeradataTable(String uri) {
        super(uri, "TERADATATABLE");
    }
```

I need to set className in upper case in `super()` constructor. I don't want to use hardcoded string.

I can't use `this.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();` in `super()`.

Is there something wring design wise?

Comment: *"I can't use `this.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();` in `super()`."* Why not? That's how you do what you've asked for. But you don't need to do it in `super()`; you can do it in the base class.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I need to put name of child class. There are other classes too like OracleTable, NetezzaTable

Comment: Yes. And? That's what `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` will give you.

Comment: The key thing to note (which may have been confusing the OP) is that if you call `this.getClass()` in the base class, it will return the class name _at runtime_. This will be the subclass and not the base class. Maybe the OP thought it would return the base class instead.

Comment: @AR.3 you are right. I got your point.

Comment: to add this information: the error messsage that will be shown using this in super() is:  Cannot refer to 'this' nor 'super' while explicitly invoking a constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need that name in the `RdbmsTable` constructor, use `this.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase()` there (rather than `super`):

```
public RdbmsTable(String uri) {
   this.uri = uri;
   this.type = this.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();
}
```

`getClass` always gives you the instance's *actual class*, regardless of where you call it from. So in `RdbmsTable` above, `this.getClass()` will return the `Class` instance for whatever class the instance actually is. If it's a `TeradataTable` instance, `this.getClass()` will return a reference to the `Class` for `TeradataTable` (not `RdbmsTable`).

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/AfwvCG):

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        new TeradataTable("foo");
    }
}

class RdbmsTable {
    public RdbmsTable(String uri) {
       System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase());
    } 

}

class TeradataTable extends RdbmsTable {
    public TeradataTable(String uri) {
        super(uri);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TERADATATABLE
```

But I'd think it would be better to use an annotation or some such to parameterize this, in case you need to use a name that isn't an *exact* match for the class name at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Would that work for you?

```
public class TeradataTable extends RdbmsTable {

    public TeradataTable(String uri) {
        super(uri, TeradataTable.class.getSimpleName().toUpperCase());
    }
```

- it does not need 'this'
- it is just the static version of your approach
- it still updates if you refactor your class names
- you can keep the other code as is